# Changing main programming language/lane due to lack of job

Tags: job-change, turkey

I'm a junior developer. So far i've been trying to work and stacking up knowledge based on C# used platforms (os, cross platform, game dev, n-tier arch, design patterns, frameworks...).
And i'm struggling with lack of job/pro people.

Recently I might have had a chance to work at a place that mainly uses PHP.
So should i change my lane (I have knowledge about html, css, php; can build up dynamic web site from scratch, but nothing serious) ?

I know sticking to a language is risky.
But at this point, thinking the time/being juni/struggle to whole new things, fear of failure and so on. Do you think that it worth? 
Time is ticking, need job and money, already waiting for a while.

Thanks so much already.

Comment: "i'm struggling with lack of job/pro people" -- does this mean you don't have a job currently? And you want us to tell you whether you should take the PHP job offer?

Comment: Ah yes, i've been unemployed for a while and looked for jobs related to c# techs. But nothing shows up. Should get php job offer or wait?

Comment: Have you ever had a C# job, if so for how long?

Comment: Yes i had, actual work and home work, nearly one year. And before i studied and interested in.

Comment: @UfukKülahlı Where do you live? This has a bit of a regional component, it seems. On my country, there are C# jobs literally _everywhere_, and those devs are currently on high demand.

Comment: @ThalesPereira Turkey. At present, a very unproductive environment is going on.

Comment: @UfukKülahlı: Go for javascript. It's the most popular language going as of now gaining more and more traction everyday.

Comment: @AbhinavSingi i've been digging in nodejs&mongodb. I put JS to list, thanks.

Comment: You don't switch paths to another language.  You expand your path to incorporate another language.  I'd view a programmer who was highly specialized in only one language as severely lacking, no matter how much experience they had.  It would be like a carpenter who specialized in hammers.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'd reassure you: being able to control more than one stack / language, is an invaluable asset in the long run. Technology changes at such a pace that nobody can guarantee you'll still develop in X after 2,3 or 5 years. Moreover, learning different syntaxes / paradigms will broaden your knowledge and potentially increase your ability to solve problems.

The question, as you put it as well, given equally valuable stacks (both PHP and .NET are) is not much about the technology but more about the working environment, finding good mentors or people experienced enough to work with, and the possibility to work on challenging projects.

Try to choose a stack that both gives some opportunity to find a job and you like enough and go for it!

Comment: In terms of human career spans, even 5 years is short term. I spent 32 years in the computer industry, and I retired early.

Comment: Thank you, this mentoring thing is so important and people always not willing to do

Comment: And remember, you can always get a job writing PHP, and continue to develop C# (or any other) skills in your personal time.

Comment: @UfukKülahlı I don't know what the market is like in Turkey, but in my area, every contract I've done has required a different set of languages/platforms. Being able to pick up a new language on-the-fly is a huge asset.

Comment: +1 for the key point, though the "technology changing so fast your skills could be out of date in 2 years" is a serious exaggeration. I hear this in the computer business all the time, and no, it's nowhere near that fast. There are still COBOL and RPG jobs out there despite those technologies being laughably behind the times. I spent 15 years doing Java before switching to VB.NET a few years ago. 20 years ago I turned down a C++ job because I figured C++ was obsolete and I didn't want to get stuck in a backwater, but today there's still plenty of C++ work going on. Etc.

Comment: @Jay It does change fast, but only as long as you have no dependencies that have to be maintained, and legacy projects to improve. Every successful C# application will still need C# guys to maintain it, and truly successful ones will still be alive ten years later - and if C# becomes unpopular in the meantime, it might very well increase your own worth. Trends are changing much faster on the web (costs associated with switching to a new paradigm/language are generally lower), but even there, PHP is still quite alive, both in serious large-scale development and small-scale "fun webs".

Comment: @Jay Your C++ is also a great example - there's still tons of dependencies that work best with C++, there's still a lot of codebases that use C++, there's still a lot of places where C++ is the cheapest option. At the same time, for example, C# is pushing the boundaries of what used to be "C++ only" - full-blown commercial games in Unity being an obvious example. But the truth is, even completely new projects with no real dependencies and legacy are being started in C++ - and today's C++ isn't 98's C++ either; it's really a new stack with decent compatibility with the old stack :)

Answer (score 14):

You're not that far down the C# path.

The most important thing you can do for your job prospects and your skills is to get a job developing.

I do think C# is a better career choice than php. But, contrary to popular belief, programming skills are mostly language agnostic. Once you have your php skills on order, go back and practice C# in your own time, then look for a C# gig.

I find it interesting that you've been revising C# knowledge? Perhaps this is why you think none of it transfers to PHP. Focus on core skills, practice and write your own projects instead.

Personal point: I worked in Javascript for a year before getting a C# job and I absolutely count it as a valuable part of my Software Development experience.

Comment: I'm not a developer but I agree, a lot of programming skills are cross language, and it's good to have knowledge in multiple fields

Comment: You're right about programming skills being cross-language... but many recruiters do not care. They want their 5 years of experience in Java, and will erase your CV even if you are the God of C#(languages are similar, though their environment is not, bu far).

Comment: A technology stack is not a career choice. Careers last a lot longer than technology stacks. I certainly wouldn't count on doing C# development in 2025. C# and Windows are rapidly losing mind-share for web development. All the famous Internet sites (except stackoverflow) are on Linux, mostly using Java or other JVM languages.

Comment: Thanks guys. And @gazzz0x2z you're right, i see all the time "at least 5 years of exp." :)

Comment: @gazzz0x2z Completely true. The alternative for the OP seems to be no work, which won't endear them to anyone. I think language changes are easier when junior. While the first couple of job searches will be the hardest, they will also be the only ones where you're not expected to hit the ground running.

Comment: @kevincline "All the famous internet sites" doesn't really mean much, though - it's not like 90% web developers work for those famous internet sites. All around where I am, web development is rapidly switching from Linux to Windows, for both small and medium-sized projects - Linux is simply proving too expensive. "Famous internet sites" like Facebook often have their own systems - something where open source platforms can help quite a bit. Some of this is adopted more widely, some will always remain vendor-specific. Use the best tool for the job, and keep mind of your local trends :)

Answer (score 8):

Over the course of about 25 years as a professional software developer, I've written software in C, C++, Java, Rexx, Visual Basic, COBOL, Perl, Python, C#, LISP, JavaScript, HTML/CSS, PHP, M68K ASM, Obj-C, Swift, IDEAL and Easytrieve. I've written web-based applications (client and server), desktop applications, command-line applications, embedded applications, spreadsheet macros, mainframe applications, mobile applications, utility scripts and code generators. I've worked in Windows, Linux, OS X, iOS, DOS, Solaris, HPUX, DGUX, Xenix, DEOS and MVS, in Education, Finance/Accounting, Telecommunications, Financial Transaction Payments, Auto Parts Retail, Avionics and Energy.

I am not trying to be boastful. There are many software developers who have had similar experiences. We have had long and happy careers creating things, solving problems, connecting things, helping people do their jobs better. The languages, operating systems, frameworks and libraries were all just tools to get the job done. I attribute my long and happy career to a desire to learn all I can, to try new things, and to find the best tools for the job, and the best ways to use them, whatever they might be. I have prioritized having work over working in a particular language/platform.

Limiting yourself to one platform/language will soon limit your opportunities, which I believe is what you are now starting to experience. If I were in your position, I'd take the PHP job and do my best to learn it like a pro. It can only make you better and more marketable to have both .NET and PHP experience.

What will make you successful is learning and applying good software design principles and implementing them in the languages and platforms that make the most sense at the time, working with other talented people and learning from them.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable experiences. This is very encouraging for me at this point.

Comment: I'm amazed this is so far down the list of answers. Any developer should feel lucky for any opportunity to learn new tools.  The more, the better; and the more you learn the easier it gets.  It's all one step closer to being a ninja.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need the money go and try for an service desk job.

Haveing knowlegde of codeing often boosts your chances in getting Jobs like that. Now you might not want or even get such a job, but not trying will not improve your situation.

PHP is in my opinion, mainly about useing opensource frameworks now a days and will require experience with a framework such as wordpress. So I doubt switching to PHP will do you much good right of the bat.

Comment: This should be a last resort.  Better to try getting a software dev job in a different field like PHP.

Comment: @dan1111 well, I would consider going to a different field to be a last Resort. Getting into a Service desk may be a stepping Stone to become a c# developer. Also I added this since nobody mentioned this option and the op states that he Needs a Job.

Comment: @Raoul Mensink thanks for your idea. In the past to save the day I worked at irrelevant jobs. Service desk job is considerable but wishing to utilize on roughly same fields.

Comment: I agree that a service desk job is better than no job.  And at least it is somewhat related work.  But you are probably not getting any development experience, so it will be limiting in terms of being able to transition into software development.

Comment: @dan1111 I think that Service desk experience has a good value for development and is often underestimated.

Comment: @dan1111 I disagree. Svc desks of larger products/systems have tiers, for example T1 = first contact; T2 = functional helpdesk; T3 = technical helpdesk.Job in T3 can be *great* opportunity to grow profesionally: you see the architecture of the whole system (thousands of source code classes and hundreds of database tables), many possible types of integrations with many systems, hunt down bugs, explain behaviors, fine-tune the performance. Many advanced tickets take 2-5 days to resolve, you have to switch between them (self-mgmt). Such a helpdesk job is unique growth experience for a programmer.

Comment: I really do not suggest getting a service desk job unless you are extremely resistant to stress. At least in the UK. In all of the first line support positions where I worked we constantly had people developing physical and mental stress-related conditions, and this was considered part-and-parcel of the job by management.